# onTap: () async {} => moveToHome(context), in this line "=>" this is giving me error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Expected to find ')'.dart(expected_token)[It is shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebar4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method in different ways. Writing a few here

```
onTap: () => moveToHome(context),

Or

onTap : (){ moveToHome(context);},
```

if you want to call an async method you can try

```dart
onTap: () async{ await moveToHome(context);}

Or

onTap: () async => moveToHome(context),
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
onTap: () async {} => moveToHome(context),
```

To:

```
onTap: () async {
  moveToHome(context);
},
```

Or:

```
onTap: () async => moveToHome(context),
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use either {} or => ,

either :

```
onTap: () async {moveToHome(context); },
```

or :

```
onTap: () async => moveToHome(context),
```